# View plots from remote python interpreter natively in PyCharm (sciview)

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh, pycharm

I am using a local install of PyCharm Professional on OSX to connect to a remote python interpreter on a Google Cloud DataProc cloud.

It's taken me a while, but now I have nearly everything working - I can interactively execute code on the remote machine, view outputs in the iPython terminal, and even view remote plots locally via x11 forwarding.

The only thing I cannot figure out is how to get PyCharm to display these plots 'natively' (i.e. in the 'SciVew' plot window). I miss this as it keeps a history of old plots.

Any idea why my remote plots are only showing in a separate xQuartz window and not natively?

Comment: select "Debug" first will let ssh interpretor plot show in Scien, I have no idea why [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEtIa.png)

Comment: what do you mean by 'select debug'?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR Run your project in debug mode once.**  Plots will appear.  Then you can resume running the project in normal mode after doing the debug trick once.

---

SciView plot brokenness with remote interpreters appears to be related to a PyCharm bug.  But [there is a workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32668).

> It is sufficient to run initially your python project in the debug
>   mode or in "Edit configurations" untag "Run with Python Console"
>   before the first run. Remote plots will appear in SciView. Then you
>   can again undo your configuration changes by tagging "Run with Python
>   Console" and remote plots will still work.

Some people start an x-forwarding ssh session in parallel, but x-forwarding is notoriously unpleasant and unreliable, so I wouldn't advise it.