# matplotlib is not plotting using Pycharm remote ssh interpreter

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm trying to plot the metrics of my CNN model after training.

I'm using Pycharm remote interpreter, my machine OS is Ubuntu, and the remote server os is Ubuntu also.

I tried many solutions but no luck! none have worked!

1. I've tried to run the code in [debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049368/view-plots-from-remote-python-interpreter-natively-in-pycharm-sciview)
2. [Changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703253/matplotlib-on-pycharm-with-remote-ssh-intepreter) to a non-interactive backend, Changing the display configuration, forwarding SSH -XY.
3. Using ( plt.show(block=True) ) and ( plt.interactive(False) ) didn't work.

Are there any other solutions? maybe my plotting code is not correct!

```
plt.plot(history.history['binary_accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_binary_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation'], loc='upper left')
plt.show(block=True)
```